# How to set up Django MySQL Database on pythonanywhere?

Tags: python, mysql, django

It's the first time I'm deploying a site using MySQL instead of SQLite3, so I'm quite new at this, after reading some documentation I found out that I have to change some files like this :

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'my_site_db',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '?', #currently using pythonanywhere (not on localhost)           
        'PORT': '?',  
    }
}
```

**manage.py**

```
try:
    import pymysql
    pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
except:
    pass
```

*(PyMySQL==0.7.10, Django 1.9, Python 3.5)*

When I run the Bash Console using `python manage.py migrate` I get this error message :

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")

I thought it has something to do with the `HOST` and the `PORT` from the Database configurations, I don't know what I should add in these, does it have to do with MySQL, PythonAnywhere or even my own domain ? How can I resolve this problem and set up MySQL correctly with Django 3.5 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/UsingMySQL/) guide. I used it to deploy my webapp.

[image]

Comment: What should I enter in <your_mysql_hostname>, the domain name ?

Comment: On the dashboard, your connection settings should be listed.
`To start using MySQL, you'll need to go to the MySQL tab on your dashboard, and set up a password. You'll also find the connection settings (host name, username) on that tab, as well as the ability to create new databases.`

Comment: thanks, worked ! the article you provided is not ranked on the first results of SEO, so it was difficult to find something to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use in this way

**Username :**  johndoe

**Database name :** socialdatabase

**Host :** xyz.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com

**User :** johndoe

**Name :** johndoe$socialdatabase

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'my_site_db', # Username$database name
    'USER': 'username', #Username:
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': '?', # Database host address           

}
}
```