# Pythonanywhere:Access denied for user 'Ujwal97'@'10.0.04' (using password:YES) Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to deploy my django app on pythonanywhere by cloning from my github.
          When migrating, I'm getting access denied error followed by (using password:YES),here is the a screenshot of that,

[image: Error Image]

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Have you checked that the username and password are definitely correct?  The one you should use for the database is stored in a file called .my.cnf in your home directory on PythonAnywhere.

Comment: where to use that password present in .my.cnf

Comment: In your Django database settings.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me like your database settings are wrong. Your database hostname on PythonAnywhere should look something like `yourusername.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com`

Check the Database page in your PythonAnywhere dashboard for the correct settings.

**Edit**: you must use the hostname, username and password from your dashboard in the Django settings file. The adress 10.0.0.4 indicates that your current settings file does not contain the correct settings.

Comment: `Ujwal97.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com` its the same way as said

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your DB settings on `yourapp/settings.py` as mentioned in [pythonanywhere guide](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/UsingMySQL/)

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': '<your_username>$<your_database_name>',
    'USER': '<your_username>',
    'PASSWORD': '<your_mysql_password>',
    'HOST': '<your_mysql_hostname>',
  }
}
```

There is also an existing [post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42399671/how-to-set-up-django-mysql-database-on-pythonanywhere?rq=1) that might be helpful